# force to compile a specific file as Objective-C/file type, but the entire project as Objective-C++

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm adding some features to a project that already exist. It works as expected.

Then I added few files from an open library to that project.

Now, Xcode fails to compile the whole project.

Investigating why, I found out that the problem is the "Compile source as" flag, it is set by default to "Objective-C++".

Switching that flag to other value makes Xcode to complain. Hundreds of errors in any case.
I have the idea the previous dev did this to avoid renaming .c, .cpp, .m to .mm. He is not here anymore. So, hard to say.

Any idea how to solve this?
I see few options:

1. Either I rename the files as necessary. Which means hundreds of
   files renamed. Or
2. I force Xcode to compile a specific file as
   Objective-C/file type, but the entire project as Objective-C++ Or
3. I create a small project, and then produce a shared library.

I would like to continue with option 2. Is it possible? and how?

Any other idea?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting the type of the file in the Identity and Type in the side panel?  If you change the type of file to Objective-C it will compile as Objective-C no matter what the extension is.

Comment: @StephenJohnson that should be an answer, surely? i.e. Xcode allows option (2) and here is the relevant drop down... (EDIT: (1) also wouldn't be hard to automate, see e.g. http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57411491-263/how-to-batch-rename-files-using-automator-in-os-x/ )

Comment: @Stephen Johnson: tried that. Did not work.

Comment: @Tommy: Problem about this is, not everything is Objective-C++. I have to selectively change .m, .c, .m to .mm. Say if an Objective-C++ is included in an objective-C file, then the last one needs to be Objective C++ too

Comment: In the long-run, option 1 is better.  It might take time, but at the end of the day you will have consistent source file names that everyone will understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went thru the easiest way: forcing Xcode to compile a specific file as Objective-C, but the entire project as Objective-C++.

Added the compiler flag `-x objective-c` to each file in Build Phases> 'Compile source as'